# Best way to load edit/save/cancel images in table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

In a table with many rows, the last cell in each row contains an anchor wrapped around an image of a pencil (edit).

Is there a performance trick so that every row doesn't have to load a separate instance of the same image? Or do browsers cache this anyway, and it's nothing to worry about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers will cache the image and only request it once.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. Guess it's the VS dev server that is making things deceptively slow